# Http - Do files with expires headers send requests?

Tags: http, caching, request, google-chrome-devtools, expires-header

I just read that files that do have Expires Headers should not be requested again until they expire.

While testing some caching stuff I wonderd why files do have a size and do consume time on "Content Download" on chrome dev tools, even if they got a max-age set and should be loaded from cache without sending any request?

Any explanations?

[image: Expires headers, but request]

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245767/is-chrome-ignoring-control-cache-max-age):

> Chrome appears to be ignoring your Cache-Control settings if you're reloading in the same tab. If you copy the URL to a new tab and load it there, Chrome will respect the cache control tags and reuse the contents from the cache.