# Chrome ignores the ETag header and just uses the in memory cache/disk cache

Tags: google-chrome, http, nginx, server

If I understand correctly, the flow for using ETags works as described now:

- Browser sends the request to the server. Server sends back the image with an ETag
- Browser saves the ressource along with the ETag
- On the next request, the browser sends the request with the header `If-None-Match` containing the saved ETag.

When returning a response, chrome dev tools tells me these are my headers

```
Cache-Control:max-age=7200
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Thu, 27 Apr 2017 13:42:57 GMT
ETag:"b36f59c868d4678033d318a182658e18371df8f5"
Expires:Thu, 27 Apr 2017 15:42:57 GMT
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Debug-Token:873c8f
X-Debug-Token-Link:http://localhost:8081/_profiler/873c8f
```

Now, when I reload the page, the new image isn't gathered, though. It's saved through Chrome's in-memory cache or disk cache as you can see here

[image: Chrome dev tab]

But why is this happening? I sent an ETag so why does the browser not make another request to the server but instead uses it's own cache?

The reason I'm asking is, that we want to cache our images, but as soon as they change, they should be updated immedietely. Why does Chrome do that?

**Update**
I just noticed that it works as intendent on Firefox, so this seems to be a chrome "feature" and not a configuration one.

**Update 2**
After setting my new headers for image like this

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Thu, 27 Apr 2017 14:44:57 GMT
ETag:"e5b18bdebe44ed4bba3acb6584d9e6a81692ee27"
Expires:Fri, 27 Oct 2017 14:44:57 GMT
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Debug-Token:3447a6
X-Debug-Token-Link:http://localhost:8081/_profiler/3447a6
```

Chrome still uses the disk cache to laod the data. This is my nginx now

```
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "max-age: 0, must-revalidate";
}
```

**Update 3**
I just did some further research. As soon as the Expires tag is set, Chrome uses the in-memory or disk-cache. Same with `max-age`. Which I don't understand, even when `must-revalidate` is set, as soon as `Expires` or `max-age=>0` is set, Chrome doesn't reload the ressource.

Answer (score 8):

The server is telling chrome that the resource is good for the next 2 hours (7200 seconds). Presumably your second request was sooner than that.

You would be better served with `max-age: 0` or perhaps `max-age: 0, must-revalidate`. Then while you'll never get a fully-cached operation (not even bothering to hit the server) you can still have the server send `304 Not Modified` responses to tell the browser that it can use the cached entity (and update any metadata based on headers if applicable) so while you still have a request-response happening only around 300bytes will be sent rather than however many kilobytes or more the entity is.

Comment: That's what we are currently doing. The request comes to the server and we check for ETag. If it's the same, we return a `304` response. The thing is, that it works as intended. In Firefox, after updating the image, the new image gets loaded instantly. But not Chrome. So I'm not sure, do you think it's a configuration error rather than a Chrome error?

Comment: Second note: I just checked the request headers of CHrome after an image got cached. There is no `If-None-Match` headers set there. Firefox sends this header, so that's why it probably works.

Comment: Third note: This is probably because of my nginx configuration. I should definetly have a look at it first and remove the headers there.

Comment: Fourth and final note: Thank you. This solved the issue! Setting the headers in Nginx made it work. Do you prefer `max-age: 0, must revalidate, private` or `public` instead?

Comment: Fitfth note...: I'm sorry dude^^. Chrome still does not reload the page and still uses the disk cache.

Comment: I have the same issue... Cache-Control is absent but Chrome still thinks he can cache it. It is strange default behavior.

Comment: @Maxim the standards allow caching if there is no headers related to caching sent and not query string in the URI, largely because of a history where servers weren't sending cache-control headers because they didn't exist yet. If you want to specify whether something can be cached or not, specify whether it can be cached or not.

Comment: @JonHanna I have ETag in a response, so there are 2 different behaviors in FF and Chrome. FF shows me 304 as status code, and Chrome shows 200 OK and "from memory/from disk".

Comment: @Musterknabe i'm having the same issue where Chrome is not sending If-None-Match where Firefox does. Were you able to figure out why?

Comment: @manni No, it seems like this is just the way Chrome behaves. IMO they go against a standard for performance. Don't agree with them on that one though

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else who might land here, note that **Chrome does not cache anything if there are *any* SSL errors** (such as if you're using a self-signed certificate).

Original post that clued me in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55101722/9536265

Chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110649 (and it appears they will never fix it, which seems ridiculous since almost all developers will be developing in that very situation)

I have not been able to confirm with documentation, but the behavior appears to be the same with Edge Chromium.  Firefox, on the other hand, will happily follow standard cache practices for sites using "Not secure" certificates such as those with imperfectly-matching site names or self-signed certificates.  I have not tested Safari.

Answer (score 4):

For ETags to be used and the browser to send the `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` headers, the cache control **must** be set to `no-cache`.

Either by the server using the [`Cache-Control: no-cache` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) or by the browser through the [`Request.cache = 'no-cache'` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache).

---

Read more about the cache options here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post but this is how we solved it.

@Musterknabe *Comment on your update 3:*

The same thing happened with us, even after setting 
`must-revalidate` chrome was not reloading fresh resources. I found out that since resources were already present in clients/browser cache memory they were being served from memory cache and the new request(to get static resources) was not firing resulting. So response headers were not updated with `must-revalidate`

**To fix this problem we used two steps:**
1. Changed resource file names - To make sure new request will be fired
  2. Added cache-control headers to static files(In startup.cs) - To take care of future static resource file changes. So that going forward we don't have to change the resource file names.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
            {
                const int durationInSeconds = 0;
                ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
                    "must-revalidate,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope it helps.