# Static assets refresh strategy in page served from output cache

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, caching, browser

I have a site, built in ASPNET MVC5, that employs a custom Ouputcache strategy. We use a MongoDB database to store our cache and it works very well. The site feels quick and our cache persists even after an APPPool or server restart.

The problem with having such persistant cache is keeping our static assets (javascript/css etc) from going stale. When we were relying on the standard output cache from framework there was no issue, as the cache was lost every time we updated the site and restarted the apppool. But now that we have more persistant cache we need to come up with a stragegy for keeping our static assets fresh.

Our old method was to append a hash of the file contents onto the query string, so that when the contents changed the query string did too and the browser would fetch the fresh file.

But now, with persistant cache, the URL to the asset will never change. What is a good strategy for keeping our assets fresh in this scenario? We have well over 100,000 pages in our cache so we dont want to have to delete them all and build them up again every time we want to make a minor CSS or JS change.

Does anyone have any tried and tested solution for this scenario?

Comment: Have you considered using etags for your resources? Its like using a hash but in a form that doesn't require you append it to the url.

Comment: You can handle this problem in different ways, initially, there are two options that I think immediately: 1. If conceptually you know that your static files are constantly changing, you could define in the web.config the average time to refresh them. 2. You could use a flag facade parameter that tells the browser to reload the resource (you don't need to rename the file). Example: https://example.com/css?v=1 since the browser will interpret that it will be a new request but your server will ignore this parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [ETags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag), as Rani Sharim mentioned. ETags allows you to provide an identifier for which version to use in the browser cache.

ETags are kinda like fingerprints, if the ETag is already known in the cache, it will be served from the cache. If the ETag seems unknown, a new version will be retrieved and cached.

My advice is to base ETags on commit versions (if the file was modified in the commit). This way, you are assured that assets are always served fresh and your site remains quick. Unmodified assets will still be served from cache, as the ETag will remain the same.

[image]

Comment: Etags are the answer conceptually, but in practice they seem a little flaky, for example when I configure the site to use Etags in Firefox I can see a 304 response for unchanged static assets, but in Chrome, very often I get a 200 response from cache, so its not even bothering to check the server, while other times it will respond with 304 as expected. Im trying to understand the workflow to better predict how Chrome will respond

Comment: Perhaps this StackOverflow question might help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659756/chrome-ignores-the-etag-header-and-just-uses-the-in-memory-cache-disk-cache

Comment: Yeah, as suggested on that thread, it appears the answer could be "cache control must be set to no-cache". That actually makes sense, and with initial testing Chrome & FF are responding in  a consistent manner, performing 304 check every time.