# How to make Angular CLI version index.html to overcome client caching problems?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've created an application using Angular and Angular CLI.

To publish, I run `ng build --prod --aot`. It produces a `dist` folder that I upload to the web server and enjoy seeing it in action.

Yet I've configured my web server to cache things.

When a user gets the current version of my SPA, `index.html` and all `.js` files and all `.css` files are all cached.

Now that I'm deploying new version, though all of the new `.js` and `.css` files are versioned, but the old `index.html` is till there and it's cached.

I've used `Cache-Control: no-cache` header, but [seems that browsers are not consistent in this area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245767/is-chrome-ignoring-cache-control-max-age).

Is it possible to configure Angular CLI to version `index.html` too?

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense - the browser is going to request the page and the server will respond with `index.html` by default. You need to correctly configure the server caching to exclude the HTML, this isn't a problem with Angular or the CLI.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the problem is that browsers are not consistent regarding caching. We excluded that item from server's caching, and we also explicitly added `no-cache`. But it didn't work.