# @media queries not working in Chrome or Safari iOS

Tags: html, css, media-queries, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

```css
/* page positions */
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mainBody{
 position: fixed;
 top: 46px;
 left: 0px;
}

.center{
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 75%;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

#about{
 position: fixed;
 top: 50px;
 bottom: 10px;
 left: 10px;
 right: 10px;
 overflow: scroll;
}

/* fonts */
@font-face{
 font-family: Wellone;
 src: url("fonts/Fonts/Wellone/Wellone.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face{
 font-family: Brush;
 src: url("fonts/Fonts/ufonts.com_brush-script-mt.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face{
 font-family: Barkless;
 src: url("fonts/Fonts/Barkless/Barkless.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face{
 font-family: Anter;
 src: url("fonts/Fonts/Anter/Anter.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face{
 font-family: Naive;
 src: url("fonts/Fonts/Naive/Naive.otf") format("opentype");
}



/* lists */
.navlist{
 position: fixed;
 white-space: nowrap;
 float: none;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;
}

.navlist li{
 display: inline-block;
}

.navlist li a{
 display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navlist li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.desclist{
 font-family:"Times New Roman";
 font-size: 200%;
 color: black;
}

.desclist li{
 list-style-type: circle;
}



/* background pictures, slideshows */
.headerimg{
 position: fixed;
 top: 46px;
 left: 0px;
 opacity: .5;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

.headerimg2
{
 position: fixed;
 top: 46px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

.slideshow{
 position: fixed;
 top: 387px;
 left: 750px;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.mySlides{
 display: none;
 animation: fade 6s;
 /*top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

/* Fading animation */
@keyframes fade {
  0% {opacity: 0;} 
  16.66%{opacity: 1;}
  33.32% {opacity: 1;}
  49.98% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}



/* word content */
/* Anter, Naive */
p.title{
 position: fixed;
 font-family: "Bodoni MT";
 top: -30px;
 font-size: 400%;
 color: white;
}

p.title2{
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Brush;
 font-size: 400%;
 top: 15px;
 color: white;
}

p.desc{
 font-family: Barkless;
 font-size: 200%;
 color: blanchedalmond;
}

p.words{
 position: relative;
 font-family: "Times New Roman";
 text-indent: 2.0em;
 font-size: 200%;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 clear: left;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 376px){
 #mainBody{
  display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="keywords" content="wedding, wedding meadows, country wedding, rustic wedding, wedding venue, outdoor wedding, beautiful wedding, spokane wedding, cheney wedding, rustic meadows">
  <meta name="DC.title" content="Rustic Meadows">
  <meta name="description" content="Plan your perfect wedding at our beautiful country home, with gorgeous views, ample space, a rustic old-timey feel, and a caring family-run staff.">
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
  <title>Rustic Meadows</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="help.css" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="mainBody">
   <nav>
     <ul class="navlist">
       <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="package.html">Wedding Packages</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="pictures.html">Gallery</a><li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
   <img class="headerimg2" alt="rustic meadows website background" src="Pictures\RusticMeadowsWeddingBackground.png"/>
   <p class="title">Rustic</p>
   <p class="title2">Meadows</p>
   <div class="slideshow">
    <img class="mySlides fade" alt="rustic meadows wedding bride and groom" src="Pictures\RusticMeadowsBrideGroom.jpg"/>
    <img class="mySlides fade" alt="rustic meadows ceremony area" src="Pictures\RusticMeadowsCeremony.jpg"/>
    <img class="mySlides fade" alt="rustic meadows reception area" src="Pictures\RusticMeadowsReception.jpg"/>
    <img class="mySlides fade" alt="rustic meadows wedding first kiss" src="Pictures\RusticMeadowsKiss.jpg"/>
    <img class="mySlides fade" alt="rustic meadows bride and groom chairs" src="Pictures\RusticMeadowsMrMrs.jpg"/>
    <img class="mySlides fade" alt="rustic meadows night lights" src="Pictures\RusticMeadowsLights.jpg"/>
    <img class="mySlides fade" alt="rustic meadows welcome sign" src="Pictures\RusticMeadowsSign.jpg"/>
    <img class="mySlides fade" alt="rustic meadows table setup" src="Pictures\RusticMeadowsTable.jpg"/>
    <img class="mySlides fade" alt="rustic meadows walkway to ceremony" src="Pictures\RusticMeadowsWalkway.jpg"/>
    <img class="mySlides fade" alt="rustic meadows wagon wheel decoration" src="Pictures\RusticMeadowsWheel.jpg"/>
   </div>
   <script>
   var slideIndex = 0;
   showSlides();

   function showSlides() {
       var i;
       var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

       for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";  
       }
       slideIndex++;
       if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
       slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
       setTimeout(showSlides, 6000);
   }
   </script>
  </div>
 </body>  
</html>
```

so, I have what I've read on numerous posts on this site. I have the appropriate  tag in my HTML file, and I have my @media query at the end of my CSS file. The thing is, the media query works in the mobile firefox app (iPhone 6), it works in desktop browsers that I've tested, but it does not work for mobile safari and mobile chrome applications. I feel like this issue is with safari and chrome mobile apps, but I could be wrong, and just missing some sort of mishap in my code. Any help is appreciative, as I've researched this for a few days and came up with no good fixes.

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain whats not working. Your media query targets screens wider than 375px, which rules out most current mobile phones in portrait mode, are you sure thats not your problem?

Comment: so, for now i am doing all these test in portrait mode. yes you are correct though. I changed my css to where i am using "max-width: 375px". Also i am doing basic testing because this problem is driving me crazy. What ive found is in safari and chrome, i have to clear the cache and cookies everytime for the browser to accept the changes made to the website. if i simply apply the changes to my website, and "reload" the webpage, safari and chrome will not reflect the changes. firefox will instantaneously.

Comment: so im guessing from what ive found, is that maybe my content has a long "sync" time between different browsers once published to my website?

Comment: You can easily bust the browser cache when you make changes, by appending a query string to the css `<link rel="stylesheet" href="help.css?v=10" type="text/css"/>` change the number when you make a change

Comment: If you are using any build tools (gulp, webpack etc), this type of thing can be built into the build process. Alternatively, if you are using a server side language to construct your html, you can use the css files last modified time to do the same

Comment: Jason Bamber - got it. Thanks for your input. Any ideas of why Firefox seems to pull the updated info from my server instantly, but chrome and safari does not? For instance after making a change to my code on the server, I hit the refresh button in Firefox, and it updates automatically. Safari and chrome, the refresh button does nothing. I have to physically clear the cache on both of those web browsers.

Comment: Im not familiar with webkit internals, but this is probably why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245767/is-chrome-ignoring-cache-control-max-age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I found actually was that I am dealing with a browsers catching function. Rather than a problem with my @media queries. The strange thing is that Firefox loads the new web content immediately. While chrome and safari, I  have to manually clear the cache and cookies every time in order to see the changes I  made on the web server.

Edit - a fix posted by Jason bamber

You can easily bust the browser cache when you make changes, by appending a query string to the css `<link rel="stylesheet" href="help.css?v=10" type="text/css"/>` change the number when you make a change –

Answer (score 0):

Add to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="help.css" type="text/css"/>` your media property.

 It's like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 376px)" href="help.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: with this addition does it mean everything in the CSS page is under the rules of "min-width" or do I still add the @media property in my CSS file in conjunction with your solution?