# HTML meta tag for Cache-Control header does not work with chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, header, response

When opening my page I can see the cache-control header is set the right way. I look into the *Network* tab and check the *Response*. It says

`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>`

Now looking into the *Header* tab I can not find this header in the *Response Header* section.
Also other headers set by the meta tag like `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>`are not listed here:

[image]

I read this [Is Chrome ignoring Cache-Control: max-age?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245767/is-chrome-ignoring-cache-control-max-age) which mentions that you should open the url in a new tab but I tried that and many other things. Still no look for this headers to be visible.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header tab show the HTTP headers, not the meta http-equivs in HTML head.

You have to set this HTTP header in your webserver configuration or from within your programming in order to see it in the Response Header section

If you want to check, if your Cache-Control setting is working, don't just reload the page in your browser, but click in the address box and hit enter with the network tab in developer tools open and check the response code.

Comment: To see it or to get it to work? If it already works that way it's fine. I don't have to actually see it in the tab

Comment: Hey again. What do you mean by "check the response code". I opened the network panel and have the reponse body html here and can see `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>` in the html. Is that already showing me it will work?

Comment: @xetra11 [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: I don't understand what the status code has to do with the `Cache-Control` header being set right or not?

Comment: @xetra11 If you see a status code of `200` it means that your page is not cached but loaded again. If you get a `304` it means it should be taking from the cache.