# mozilla firefox ignoring the cache-control header

Tags: firefox, browser-cache, cache-control, max-age

I am loading a few thumbnail images in my application which are stored on google cloud, I have made the thumbnail objects public and set `cache-control: public, max-age:2628000`, this seems to be working on chrome where i see the images are getting loaded from cache but on mozilla firefox this is not working, **whenever i reload the page**, I always see the images are been request from the server. I have also checked that I do not have `disable cache` checked in developer tools
here is a screenshot

[image]

Everytime i see bytes transferred and the images are not loading from cache.

Any help in this would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: Hi @Hans-Helge, actually mozilla does cache, my understanding of how it works was incorrect. After reading more about it i figured that it was actually caching. So, if you open a link in mozilla and instead of reloading the page, just copy / paste the url in same or different tab, you will see mozilla does cache the images and displayes it from the cache. you can read more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245767/is-chrome-ignoring-cache-control-max-age

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for anyone who might stumble on this post, I figured out that mozilla was indeed caching the images and displaying it from the cache.

if you open a page and then copy / paste the same url in the same or new tab, you will observe that mozilla displays the cached version of the images, when you reload a page, the images will be requested from the server.

I found out the answer to my post here [Is Chrome ignoring Cache-Control: max-age?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245767/is-chrome-ignoring-cache-control-max-ag), please read this as its explained in much more detail here.

Comment: That's corret. In other words. FF caches images but a page reload using CMD + R (on Windows CTRL + R) might ignore the cached images. Only cached files using ETags are properly retrieved from the cache and shown so in the DevTools.

Comment: thanks, was stuck with this problem for some time and your answer helped

Comment: As a note, Firefox will also not cache your (text/html) page if any linked resource (ex: fonts) resulted in a 4xx. If you want your html pages to cache, resolve any 4xxs.