# Browser ignoring html/php cache headers?

Tags: php, caching, browser, browser-cache, cache-control

I am confused about cache headers.
I am trying to make the browser cache my php/html pages because they are mostly static and they would not change for a month or so.

The urls look like: `example.com/article-url` and in background that is a php page like `/article_url.php`

I tried this in PHP:

```
$cache_seconds = 60*60*24*30;
header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time()+$cache_seconds));
header("Cache-Control:public, max-age=".$cache_seconds);
```

And in browser debug window I can see that indeed the page would expire next month:

```
Request URL: https://www.example.com/article-url
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
cache-control: public, max-age=2592000
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 2352
content-type: text/html
date: Mon, 25 Nov 2019 14:23:40 GMT
expires: Wed, 25 Dec 2019 14:23:40 GMT
server: nginx
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
```

But if I access that page again, I see it was generated again, I made it print the request timestamp in footer, and I can see the page is generated again on each page load.
I was expecting browser to show exact same page from cache.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842553/1460810

Comment: From my tests, it is not a Chrome issue, it happens on Chrome or Mozilla too, I click to visit another page, then click the main page link, and the timestamp is new (page was re-generated).